# How to add processing PHP file for AJAX requests in Joomla

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I am trying to develop a form in Joomla. The basic problem is:
How can I alter the form select options depending on what the user has chosen before? I need to make several database requests, while the user fills the form. With AJAX, I will need a processing PHP file. Can someone tell me how to do this in Joomla, because with JCE File browser I can't add any.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know how to write a "normal" Joomla component that retrieves data from database and shows them in a page, here's the proposed solution.

In my example I will dynamically retrieve a list of "products" for the selected "category".

## COMPONENT: the server part of the Ajax request

Let's say we use JSON to exchange data in the Ajax call.

Within every Joomla component, you can create a JSON view, creating a file view.json.php alongside the default view.html.php. That view will be used when you add "format=json" to your query string.

So you create these additional views that use the same model to get data, but output them as a JSON string. The JSON view is usually something very simple, like this:

```
public function display()
{
    $this->products = $this->getModel()->getProducts();
    echo json_encode($this->products);
}
```

You also need to add the "tmpl=component" so that the response only contains data from the component and not the rest of the Joomla page (like modules and such).

You should end up in a situation where you can put in the browser:

```
http://yoursite/index.php?option=mycomponent&view=products&format=json&tmpl=component
```

and you will get a JSON list of products.

## Add filters to your request

Of course you only want products for the selected category so you should modify your "getProducts" model method to check for a querystring parameter like `category=xyz`.

The URL becomes

```
http://yoursite/index.php?option=mycomponent&view=products&category=1&format=json&tmpl=component
```

P.S. a more detailed discussion on how to implement the check is off topic, because it's not related to AJAX.

## JQUERY: the client part of the AJAX request

Now that you have a component that accept requests via URL and provide a JSON response you can use jQuery to get new data each time the "category" select is changed:

```
var category_select = $('#category');
var product_select = $('#product');
var request = jQuery.ajax({
    "url": 'index.php?option=mycomponents&view=products&tmpl=component&format=json&category=' + category_select.val()
    "type": "GET"
}).done(function (result) {
    result.each(function (product) {
        var new_option = jQuery('<option/>', {
            'value': product.id,
        })
        .text(product.name)
        .appendTo(product_select);
    });
})
```

This JS code should be added in the same page where you show your form.

Comment: Now, I am using 
    $query = "select * from products";
    $result=mysqli:query($conn, $query) or die ("error");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    foreach($result as $row )
    {
    $products[] = $row['product_name'];
    }
How can I do it with JSON? Could You please add that to your answer?

Comment: The simple answer is: with json_encode($products).

But what you just showed me in your comment is not really Joomla code. At the beginning of my answer I wrote "Assuming you already know how to write a "normal" Joomla component". If that is not the case, unfortunately my answer is a bit too complex to apply.